# how to make an auth requset from api backend to another api backend that i own?

Tags: node.js

I want to make a simple authentication request between two API each on separate servers, i know how to make authentication using JSON-web-tokens or sessions , from front-end to back-end calls , this is done by storing them in the browser , but how i can make authentication between separate back-end servers that i own , authentication from API to another API ?

i have tried , by using jwt-simple library , and check if decoding was valid , then i complete the process , if not then i reject it , but i don't want to do it that way , I've tried passport docs , but all i can find is they describe storing authentication in the browser , since I'm trying to use fetch request from my back-end API to another API that i own , this doesn't serve the purpose that I'm trying to reach here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand question

At the beginning you have to answer the question: What do you want to do? You have several options:

1. Authorization completely without user involvement: you know how to connect a user from server A to a user from server B and only servers authenticate it and say *I'm Kowalsky* (Eg: an additional method for generating JWT.)
2. Authorization with the password: Server A asks the user to enter login + password, and then uses this data for server B.
3. Server A sends back the user to be authorized on server B and forwarded data back to server A. (e.g.: OAuth2)

**Edit:**

Add 1. Assume that you authorize using JWT and you know how to generate it for the second server, so:

Server A knows how to generate JWT for Server B and does it.

You should use a library that allows you to perform an HTTP request, or better use a `REST client`, eg 1 result from google [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client#http-post-and-put-methods).

In a very similar way as in the frontend-client, you build an query and send it.

```
const getServerBTokenForUser = function(userData) {
    return 'Generated JWT token';
}
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

// direct way
let client = new Client();

var args = {
    path: { "id": 120, "arg1": "hello", "arg2": "world" },  
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+getServerBTokenForUser(userData) }
};

client.get("http://remote.site/rest/json/${id}/method?arg1=${arg1}&arg2=${arg2}", args,
    function (data, response) {
        // parsed response body as js object
        console.log(data);
        // raw response
        console.log(response);
    });
```

It was the fastest, though not the best method, because it creates strict dependencies.
It is better to add a method on server B, where other servers will be authorized (second authorization method, eg IP or encrypted data) and obtain JWT for specified user.

Comment: thank you for your response can you explain more on option 1 , authorization completely without user involvement , with code example

Comment: You ask a general question, expect a general answer. (updated answer)